# get wrong ogtype in object debugger

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

my tested page is here. 
`http://smartphone.mn/news/2110` . I'm using facebook object debugger, Debugger return `og:type = website` and 4 Inferred property warning (og:url,or:img, og:description, og:image).

How can fix this. Why object type return wrong?

Comment: Solved: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44453472/4899346

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You using OpenGraph meta-tags in a wrong manner. This is a code you have in page:

```
<meta name="fb:app_id" content="..." />
<meta name="og:type" content="article" />
...
```

But the fact is you MUST use property named `property` instead of `name` to specify the name of the OpenGraph data...

So to solve this you just need to replace `name` to `property` for OpenGraph meta-tags:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="..." />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
...
```