# What does it mean Inferred Property in facebook opengraph

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [get wrong ogtype in object debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953779/get-wrong-ogtype-in-object-debugger)

I have a website integrated with FB open graph. I have my objects and actions defined and now if I debug my page in the facebook debugger I get the warnings:

> Inferred Property: The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
>
> Inferred Property: The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value 
>   can be inferred from other tags.
>
> Inferred Property: The 'og:description' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
>
> Inferred Property: The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

I have founds tons of post about this issue but I am still not getting how can I fix it. On that page I have following meta tags in the header:

```
<meta content='' name='fb:appid'>
<meta content="test" name='og:description'>
<meta content="test" name='og:title'>
<meta content='...' name='og:url'>
<meta content='...' name='og:image'>
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: Solved: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44453472/4899346

Answer (score 35):

Change the 'name' tags to 'property' like -

```
<meta content="..." property="og:description"/>
<meta content="..." property="og:title"/>
```

And it should work fine. Refer to - http://ogp.me/ for examples.

Comment: perfect man its worked. thanks :D