# Override CakePHP head/header

Tags: php, header, cakephp-3.x

EDIT: I found the solution, but now there is a problem with cakePhp itself

I am using:

```
<?php if (isset($image)) echo $this->Html->meta(array('name' => 'og:image', 'content' => $image)); ?>
```

and it generates

```
<meta name="og:image" content="https://test.com/img/sharer/startseite.jpg"/>
```

Sadly Facebook doesn´t like the /> at the end (related here [Facebook Open Graph Error - Inferred Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869430/facebook-open-graph-error-inferred-property) )

I have to use it with a space - but CakePhp generates it that way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CakePHP 3, you can find templates for the HTML helper in `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/View/Helper/HtmlHelper.php`.

Copy those to `config/templates/html-templates.php` and enhance them according to your demands.

Then, in your `\App\Controller\AppController`, add

```
public $helpers = [
  ...
  'Html' => ['templates' => 'templates/html-templates'],
];
```

and use your HTML helper as usual.