# I cant figure out why all my heroku app sites are being blocked by Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, heroku, mongoose, passport.js

I'm having this issue where whenever I try and share something I've deployed to heroku on Facebook, it says:

> "You can't post this because it has a blocked link The content you're
>   trying to share includes a link that our security systems detected to
>   be unsafe:
>
> *gordonsbbq-backend.herokuapp.com (or any herokuapp site I post)*
>
> Please remove this link to continue. If you think you're seeing this
>   by mistake, please let us know."

The say to put the link in their debugger, but it rejects the link too. 
All the sites are active, it's these in particular

[coreyrodems.com](http://www.coreyrodems.com/)

[gordonsbbq.net](http://www.gordonsbbq.net/)

[gordonsbbq-backend.herokuapp.com](http://gordonsbbq-backend.herokuapp.com/)

[redivo-backend.herokuapp.com](http://redivo-backend.herokuapp.com/)

here are the associated repos

https://github.com/CoreyRo/coreyrodems

https://github.com/CoreyRo/gordonsbbq

https://github.com/CoreyRo/gordonsbbq-backend

https://github.com/CoreyRo/redivo-backend

I thought maybe it was one of the node moudles I was using, or maybe the cdns or css links. Here is some from the gordonsbbq-backend

**Package.json**

```
    {
  "name": "gordonsbbq-backend",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "server": "node server.js",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "nodemon": "nodemon server.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.5.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^2.6.0",
    "axios": "^0.17.1",
    "bcrypt": "^1.0.3",
    "body-parser": "~1.15.2",
    "connect-mongo": "^2.0.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "dotenv": "^5.0.0",
    "express": "~4.14.0",
    "express-flash": "^0.0.2",
    "express-handlebars": "^3.0.0",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "express-validator": "^4.3.0",
    "formidable": "^1.1.1",
    "hbs": "~4.0.1",
    "method-override": "^2.3.10",
    "moment": "^2.20.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.0.3",
    "mongoose-paginate": "^5.0.3",
    "morgan": "~1.7.0",
    "nl2br": "^0.0.3",
    "nodemailer": "^4.4.2",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3"
  }
}
```

**main.handlebars**

```
        <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>{{pageTitle}}</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
        <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
        <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/ms-icon-144x144.png">
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png"> -->
        <!-- Place favicon.ico in the root directory -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/animate.css@3.5.2/animate.min.css" integrity="sha384-OHBBOqpYHNsIqQy8hL1U+8OXf9hH6QRxi0+EODezv82DfnZoV7qoHAZDwMwEJvSw" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="/css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="/css/navbar.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <nav class="navbar top-bar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <a href="#" data-target="#sidebar" data-toggle="collapse" id='collapse-bars'><i class="fa fa-bars fa-lg fa-3x py-2 p-1"></i></a>  
            <div class="navbar-brand">
                <a href='/home'><h5>{{title}}</h5></a>
            </div>
            {{#if username}}
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <a class='list-group-item d-inline-block mobile-item' href="/edit-profile"><i class="fa fa-user fa-lg "></i> Edit Profile</a>
                    <a class="list-group-item d-inline-block mobile-item" href="/logout"><i class="fa fa-power-off fa-lg "></i> </span>Logout</a>
                    <li id='drop-down' class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">{{user.username}}</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class='dropdown-item' href="/edit-profile"><i class="fa fa-user fa-lg "></i> Edit Profile</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/logout"><i class="fa fa-power-off fa-lg"></i> <span class="d-none d-md-inline"></span>Logout</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            {{/if}}
        </nav>



            <div id='flex-wrap' class="row d-flex d-md-block flex-nowrap wrapper">
                <div class="col-lg-2 float-left col-1 pl-0 pr-0 collapse width show" id="sidebar">
                    <div class="list-group border-0 card text-center text-md-left">
                        {{#if username}}
                        <a class='list-group-item d-inline-block collapsed' href="/home">
                            <li class="active">
                                <i class="fa fa-home fa-lg "></i> <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Home
                                </span>
                            </li>
                        </a>
                        <a class='list-group-item d-inline-block collapsed' href="/blog">
                            <li class=" li-text">
                                <i class="fa fa-database fa-lg "></i> <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Blog Entries
                                </span>
                            </li>
                        </a>
                        </a>
                        <a class='list-group-item d-inline-block collapsed' href="/newpost">
                            <li class=" li-text">
                                <i class="fa fa-plus-square fa-lg "></i> <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Create New Blog Entry
                                </span>
                            </li>
                        </a>
                        <a class='list-group-item d-inline-block collapsed' href="/edit-profile">
                            <li class=" li-text">
                                <i class="fa fa-user fa-lg "></i> <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Edit Profile
                                </span>
                            </li>
                        </a>
                        <a class='list-group-item d-inline-block collapsed' href="/change-password">
                            <li class=" li-text">
                                <i class="fa fa-cog fa-lg "></i> <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Change Password
                                </span>
                            </li>
                        </a>
                        {{#if user.isAdmin}}
                        <a class='list-group-item d-inline-block collapsed' href="/register">
                            <li class=" li-text">
                                <i class="fa fa-user-plus fa-lg "></i> <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Register New User
                                </span>
                            </li>
                        </a>
                        <a class='list-group-item d-inline-block collapsed' href="/manage-users">
                            <li class=" li-text">
                                <i class="fa fa-users fa-lg "></i> <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Manage Users
                                </span>
                            </li>
                        </a>
                        {{/if}}
                        <a class='list-group-item d-inline-block collapsed' href="/logout">
                            <li class=" li-text">
                                <i class="fa fa-power-off fa-lg "></i> <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Logout
                                </span>
                            </li>
                        </a>
                        {{/if}}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <main class="col-lg-10 float-left col px-5 pl-md-2 pt-2 main" data-bucket='empty'>
                    {{{body}}}
                </main>
            </div>
        </div>


    {{!-- <a href="#menu1" class="list-group-item d-inline-block collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sidebar" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Item 1     </span> </a>
        <div class="collapse" id="menu1">
            <a href="#menu1sub1" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">Subitem 1 </a>
            <div class="collapse" id="menu1sub1">
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu1sub1">Subitem 1 a</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu1sub1">Subitem 2 b</a>
                <a href="#menu1sub1sub1" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">Subitem 3 c </a>
                <div class="collapse" id="menu1sub1sub1">
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu1sub1sub1">Subitem 3 c.1</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu1sub1sub1">Subitem 3 c.2</a>
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu1sub1">Subitem 4 d</a>
                <a href="#menu1sub1sub2" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">Subitem 5 e </a>
                <div class="collapse" id="menu1sub1sub2">
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu1sub1sub2">Subitem 5 e.1</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu1sub1sub2">Subitem 5 e.2</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu1">Subitem 2</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu1">Subitem 3</a>
        </div> --}}
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-fileinput/4.4.7/js/fileinput.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

If I should give any more info let me know, I'm sort of at at a dead end here in my searches for what the cause is. The Facebook message is so vague and the community forums either aren't relevant to my issue or they say to use a link debugger, which rejects my links outright.

Any help or direction is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You seem to be missing [og tags](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) another question about this issue is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41553304/1641941)

Comment: hmm, I can't even put the link in that debugger. Thanks for the response, I don't really know what og is but I'll look into it.

Comment: This might simply be blocked based on the server IP - remember that you are sharing this free hosting service with many other users, so if one of them on "your" machine misbehaves, this quickly becomes an "in the same boat" type of situation. If you want reliability, then don't rely on free hosting.