# Wordpress All In One SEO plugin not sharing to Facebook wall

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I use to implement Facebook's OpenGRaph protocol on my pages (wordpress) based on All In One SEO plugin.

With each page:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="article">
<meta property="og:title" content="my_title">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://my_site.jp">
<meta property="og:description" content="my_content">
<meta property="article:published_time" content="my_published_time">
<meta property="article:modified_time" content="my_modified_time">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="my_site_name">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://my_site.jp/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/my_image.png">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="600">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="315">
<meta property="og:locale" content="my_cocale">
```

But i get these error when checking with [Facebook developer debug](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/):

```
URL returned a bad HTTP response code.
Inferred Property
The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
```

I have ref from: [Facebook Open Graph Error - Inferred Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869430/facebook-open-graph-error-inferred-property)

But I don't have any solution. Have your solution for this problem?

[image]

Comment: What URL are you debugging?

Comment: URL for debugging: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fcomona.jp%2F47456

Comment: What is your URL!

Comment: My URL is http://comona.jp/47456, but It is fixed.
I have just URL with the same error: http://comona.jp/47875

Comment: Update URL: http://comona.jp/48028

Comment: I am in the same situation as you @DinhNguyen. If you have found the solution and read this comment, please add some words of solution to your question. This will be usefull for me and others as well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since your initial link's image issue is now fixed, it's difficult to say what was wrong with it, especially since the snippet you provided seems fine. With the latter link you provided, though, I'm getting this error:

`The 'og:description' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.`

This is because there isn't an explicitly `og:description` tag available on the page.

Someone unrelated: I'm noticing duplicate `twitter:card` and related tags. This shouldn't cause Open Graph to not work, but should be resolved.

My hunch is that you're using multiple plugins that might be providing the same thing, causing clashes and unexpected behavior. This is why I tend to stay away from "provide it all" plugins, and instead use plugins that do one thing and one thing well. In your case, this might mean using a simpler, more predictable plugin like Complete Open Graph:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/complete-open-graph/

Comment: Thank your solution. But my customer request to using All In One SEO. So I need fixing this error instead of change to plugin others.