# Had all relavant opengraph social meta (created by AIOS) but facebook debug failed to recognize

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I know this is an old topic but I've digged dozens of related questions and solutions but neither of them works.

Some of questions I've read:
[Can't fix: 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41553304/cant-fix-ogimage-property-should-be-explicitly-provided-even-if-a-value-ca)

[Wordpress All In One SEO plugin not sharing to Facebook wall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44175687/wordpress-all-in-one-seo-plugin-not-sharing-to-facebook-wall)

My test url for facebook debug:

https://trangthietbiytehcm.com

Also, I debuged via Facebook sharing debug and Facebook Object debug

Here is Facebook Object debug:

[image: Facebook Object debug result]

Here is Facebook Sharing debug:

[image: Facebook Sharing debug result]

here is the post's head tab:

[image: Head html]

I also add that sometimes this post could be displayed well (including image thumbnail) on my facebook page but most of time it did not.

I've cleared my wordpress caches.

Absolutely, I can read the social opengraph tab on my post but facebook failed to read them. I do not know the reason behind this problem. Please help me to be clear! thanks

EDIT:
This is a capture of the fact that sometimes Facebook receives my blog post well. And the post link is: https://trangthietbiytehcm.com/uncategorized/san-pham-test-lan-2/
And I wnat to add that the above test link (https://trangthietbiytehcm.com/uncategorized/bai-viet-mau/) also has the same fact as this

[image]

EDIT (UPDATE):
After months of be frustrated with this problem, I even tested on another [new web](http://ppqprecision.com/) on new host server. I've finally found that the reason of this problem is the page cache function of [the W3 total cache](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/w3-total-cache-caused-isssue-with-ogimage-image-thumbnail-when-posting-to-fb/)

Comment: This is what you are sending to Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/echo/?q=https%3A%2F%2Ftrangthietbiytehcm.com%2Funcategorized%2Fbai-viet-mau%2F . Nothing

Comment: I do not know why Facebook received nothing while my html head of that post includes exactly what Facebook OG requires. Do you have any ideas or guidelines for me to overcome this stack?

Comment: @WizKid: I added some words to my question, hope to inform you and other experts more insight to help me. Thanks

Comment: The problem is that your server is not sending anything back to Facebook

Comment: Thank you, let me recheck again. I also add lazy load plugin in my site. I think I should try to deactive some plugins to see the impact.

Answer (score 0):

We've found this issue to be related to W3 Total Cache, too. Specifically, it's the *Wordpress Dashboard > Performance > Minify > Eliminate render-blocking CSS by moving it to HTTP body* feature. What this does is shove all the CSS right after the  tag, moving all the other header tags down.

And it seems Facebook (and Twitter?) only parse a fixed amount of the page before deciding to try and render... and if your CSS is long, well, it never sees your og:image tag (or any others, like Title, etc).

We have yet to find a good fix which still allows this feature to be used.